# Modify Date Picker In iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, datepicker

In my app, I displayed a date picker But it also shows the previous dates.

**I just want to display date from Today's Date.**

I never want to display the old dates from Today in Date-picker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `[NSDate date]` or `Date()` returns the current today's date.

**In Objective-C**

Set the date picker's minimumDate property:

```
datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
```

**In Swift 4.x**

```
datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
```

(Where datePicker is a reference to your `UIDatePicker` )